# How to use JButtons with cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, cardlayout

I have been attempting a nice UI for fun because I am very new to java. I have learned how the cardlayout works, but I have an issue with the JButtons not showing the correct card in my cardlayout. I am using ItemListeners with Actionlisteners to change the cardlayout. here is the code that i have...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginCards implements ItemListener, ActionListener
{
    JPanel cards; //a panel that uses CardLayout
    JButton login1;
    JButton login2;
    JButton login3;

    final static String STUDENTPANEL = "Student";
    final static String INSTRUCTORPANEL = "Instructor";
    final static String DEPTSTAFFPANEL = "Department Staff";
    final static String DEPTSTAFFOPTIONS = "";
    final static String INSTRUCTOROPTIONS = "";
    final static String STUDENTOPTIONS ="";

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) 
    {       
        login1 = new JButton("Login");
        login2 = new JButton("Login");
        login3 = new JButton("Login");      
        login1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {           
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());

                cl.show(cards, STUDENTOPTIONS);
            }
        });

        login2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {           
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());

                cl.show(cards, INSTRUCTOROPTIONS);
            }
        });

        login3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {           
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());

                cl.show(cards, DEPTSTAFFOPTIONS);
            }
        });

        //Put the JComboBox in a JPanel to get a nicer look.
        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        String comboBoxItems[] = { STUDENTPANEL, INSTRUCTORPANEL, DEPTSTAFFPANEL };
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);

        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);

        //Create the "cards".
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();

        card1.add(new JLabel("UserName: "));
        card1.add(new JTextField("Student UserName", 20));
        card1.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        card1.add(new JPasswordField(20));
        card1.add(login1);

        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

        card2.add(new JLabel("UserName: "));
        card2.add(new JTextField("Instructor UserName", 20));
        card2.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        card2.add(new JPasswordField(20));
        card2.add(login2);       

        JPanel card3 = new JPanel();

        card3.add(new JLabel("UserName: "));
        card3.add(new JTextField("Dept. Staff UserName", 20));
        card3.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        card3.add(new JPasswordField(20));
        card3.add(login3);

        JPanel instructorViewCard = new JPanel();

        instructorViewCard.add(new JLabel("instructorViewCard"));

        JPanel deptStaffViewCard = new JPanel();

        deptStaffViewCard.add(new JLabel("deptStaffViewCard"));

        JPanel studentViewCard = new JPanel();

        studentViewCard.add(new JLabel("studentViewCard"));

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, STUDENTPANEL);
        cards.add(card2, INSTRUCTORPANEL);
        cards.add(card3, DEPTSTAFFPANEL);
        cards.add(deptStaffViewCard, DEPTSTAFFOPTIONS);
        cards.add(studentViewCard, STUDENTOPTIONS);
        cards.add(instructorViewCard, INSTRUCTOROPTIONS);        
        pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) 
    {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());

        cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OUR System");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        LoginCards demo = new LoginCards();

        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try 
        {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InstantiationException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

If you notice that no matter which button you are on (1,2, or 3) you always get the same card layout with the label "instructorViewCard". I want to be able to view the studentViewCard with the login1 button and so on. I am just not sure what I am missing to do this. Does anyone see the answer? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not given a unique name to the card identifiers for the dept staff, instructor and student options...

```
final static String DEPTSTAFFOPTIONS = "";
final static String INSTRUCTOROPTIONS = "";
final static String STUDENTOPTIONS = "";
```

This basically means it's using `instructorViewCard` as the same view for each of the elements (been the last one added), as the cards are managed by a `Map` internally...

Comment: THANKS!!! i will mark this as correct in 2 more mins. I just added some letters to identify it like the others. idk how I thought it was ok to go without those.  -.-

Comment: Easy to do when dealing with something new ;)